# Swift: class and properties - all only initialized once

Tags: class, swift, struct, static, singleton

I'm looking to have a class or struct (does not matter) with properties, where everything may only be initialized once in the app. Any attempt to modify the class or its properties will fail or not be possible.

Is this possible?

I've come up with this so far:

```
public struct ScreenInfo
{
    static var scaleFactor:Int = 0

    public init(initialScaleFactor:Int)
    {
        if (ScreenInfo.scaleFactor == 0) {
            ScreenInfo.scaleFactor = initialScaleFactor
        }
    }

    public static func getScaleFactor()
    -> Int
    {
        return scaleFactor
    }
}

let si1:ScreenInfo = ScreenInfo(initialScaleFactor:11)
ScreenInfo.getScaleFactor()    // = 11

let si2:ScreenInfo = ScreenInfo(initialScaleFactor:22)
ScreenInfo.getScaleFactor()    // = 11
```

Comment: try to use singleton pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is somewhat unusual, but it is possible.

```
public struct ScreenInfo {
  private static var _scaleFactor: Int?
  public static var scaleFactor: Int? {
    set {
      if _scaleFactor == nil {
        _scaleFactor = newValue
      } else {
        // Optionally throw an exception or something
      }
    }
    get {
      return _scaleFactor
    }
  }
}

ScreenInfo.scaleFactor       // nil
ScreenInfo.scaleFactor = 5
ScreenInfo.scaleFactor       // 5
ScreenInfo.scaleFactor = 15
ScreenInfo.scaleFactor       // 5
```

Comment: Almost perfect example, the property `_scaleFactor` even if set to private is accessible and can be set which in turn will change both `_scaleFactor` and `scaleFactor`.

Comment: It's accessible in the same file, yes. If you put the struct's definition in its own file, it will not be accessible.

Comment: Yeah I just saw that in playgrounds. thx...Ok back to being Perfectionism!